# Как вывести массив в строку, а не в столбик? (без кавычек)

Tags: java

Подскажите пожалуйста, как вывести массив в строку?
Для примера внизу показан простой массив, которые выводится в столбик.

```
     public static void main(String args[]){
        int[] a = {6, 88, 13, 91, 25, 59};
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(a[i]);
        }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`System.out.println ()` - выводит сообщение на экран и после этого осуществляется перевод курсора на новую строчку.

`System.out.print ()` - выводит сообщение на экран и после этого не осуществляется перевод курсора на новую строчку

Используйте второй способ и будет вам счастье=)

**Пример 1:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Я изучаю");
        System.out.println ("Java");
        System.out.println ("Ура!");
    }
```

**Вывод:**

> Я изучаю
>
> Java
>
> Ура!

**Пример 2:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print("Я изучаю");
        System.out.print("Java");
    }
```

**Вывод:**

> Я изучаюJava

Вот еще одна штука:

```
System.out.println("Some ");
System.out.println("text");
```

и

```
System.out.print("Some \n");
System.out.print("text");
```

Распечатают одинаковый текст

> Some
>
> text

т.к. символ '\n' так же делает перенос курсора на следующую строку